# Docker doesn't work when using getsentry/sentry-cli

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sentry

I want to upload my frontend to sentry, but I need to get the folder using `docker`  commands. However when I use `image: getsentry/sentry-cli` 
docker doesn't works and e.g. in `before_script` I get error that docker doesn't exist

```js
sentry_job:
  stage: sentry_job
  image: getsentry/sentry-cli
  services:
    - docker:18-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" registry.gitlab.cz
  script:
   # script...
.   # Get the dist folder from the image
- mkdir frontend_dist
- docker run --rm -v $PWD/frontend_dist:/mounted --entrypoint="" $IMAGE /bin/sh -c "cp /frontend/dist /mounted"
- ls frontend_dist

  tags:
    - dind
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: As you use `image: getsentry/sentry-cli`, all the commands of `before_script` and `script` are run *inside a container created from the image*, and given that the image itself does not contain the `docker` executable, you get the behavior you observe. BTW, could you elaborate a bit on what you'd like to do, namely when you say `get the folder using docker commands`?

Comment: I want to copy one folder from my git branch to temp folder and use that temp folder to upload sourcemap to sentry. I tried doing separate stages and in first stage only copy the folder and use sentry image in second stage but that copied folder is not available in the second stage. So I'm not sure how to make both them work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to use **a single job** (to have the same build context) and specify **`docker:stable`** as the job `image` (along with **`docker:stable-dind`** as a `service`).

This setup is called [docker-in-docker](http://blog.teracy.com/2017/09/11/how-to-use-docker-in-docker-dind-and-docker-outside-of-docker-dood-for-local-ci-testing/) and this is the standard way to allow a GitLab CI `script` to run `docker` commands [(see doc)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#container-registry-examples).

Thus, you could slightly adapt your `.gitlab-ci.yml` code like this:

```
sentry_job:
  stage: sentry_job
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE: "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" registry.gitlab.cz
  script:
    - git pull "$IMAGE"
    - mkdir -v frontend_dist
    - docker run --rm -v "$PWD/frontend_dist:/mounted" --entrypoint="" "$IMAGE" /bin/sh -c "cp -v /frontend/dist /mounted"
    - ls frontend_dist
    - git pull getsentry/sentry-cli
    - docker run --rm -v "$PWD/frontend_dist:/work" getsentry/sentry-cli
  tags:
    - dind
```

Note: the `git pull` commands are optional (they ensure Docker will use the latest version of the images).

Also, you may need to change the definition of variable `IMAGE`.

Comment: How should I execute e.g. ` sentry-cli releases new $V` ?  my build job fails now at this line. do I have to write `docker run` before each command? sorry for dumb questions

Comment: @user122222 I'm not familiar with `sentry-cli` so I don't know if there is some "state" shared between successive calls of `sentry-cli`. Hopefully this is not the case, in which case you can indeed prepend each of your commands like this: `- docker run --rm -v "$PWD/frontend_dist:/work" getsentry/sentry-cli releases new "$V"` (regarding the mountpoint path `/work`, I've not tested it but this corresponds to what is indicated [in sentry's doc](https://docs.sentry.io/cli/installation/#docker-image)).